# How to scape an space to get the MD5 SH1 To generate a key with keytools for android map

Tags: android, google-maps, cmd, android-studio, keytool

Hi I have the following problema when I try to get the MD5 result with this Command:
"keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\3D Apps.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass Android"

this is the message:
"option not allowed APP.android\debug.keystore"

I have thry many thinhs without success

-like complete the 3D with ~1 like this "C:\Users\3D~1...." same problema. 
-Put a ^ to scape the space without success.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the file name in quotes:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\3D Apps.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass Android
```